# Apache Common Pools migration from version 1 to version 2 and the exhausted actions

Tags: java, apache-commons-pool

In Apache Commons Pool 1, the class [GenericObjectPool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html) had the possibility to define three actions to react to an exhausted pool:

- Fail
- Block
- Grow

Now, in version 2 I do not see these three options and the class [GenericObjectPool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html) seems to have only the possibility to specify if the pool must block or not when exhausted.

According with method [`borrowObject`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#borrowObject-long-), it seems that the block when exhausted option only allows for covering actions FAIL and BLOCK. But how can I make the pool follow the GROW action?

Answer (score 0):

I've found in the [changelog](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/changes-report.html)

> Remove WhenExhuastedAction.GROW since it is equivalent to
>   WhenExhuastedAction.FAIL with a maxActive value of Integer.MAX_VALUE

Therefore it should be possible to make it with the above configuration.